# How to Save HTML to mysql using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to post some html though a form to a php page and then trying to save that html into database 
the problem which I am facing is that when I save this to database it includes many html entities with it

for example my original html code is

```
<div class="flexslider">
 <ul class="slides">
<li class="slide slide--text" data-text="Great Plans And Pricing To Help You Get Started With Your E-Commerce Business">
  <div class="overdiv" style="position: absolute;">
           <form method="post" action="https://www.marclick.com/customer/account/create/">
              <div>
                 <input required type="email" name="email" value="" style="border-radius:10px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
                 <div class="text-left"></div>
                 <input type="submit" value="Get Your Online Shop Now!" class="btn btn-warning btn--decorated">
              </div>
           </form>
           <p class="text-left">No Credit Card Required</p>
 </div>
  <img src="img/home_slider/1.jpg" alt="">
</li>
</ul>
```

But When I save it db it becomes

```
    <p>&lt;!-- Flex full width slider --&gt;<br />
&lt;div class=&quot;flexslider&quot;&gt;<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
&nbsp; &lt;ul class=&quot;slides&quot;&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&lt;li class=&quot;slide slide--text&quot; data-text=&quot;Great Plans And Pricing To Help You Get Started With Your E-Commerce Business&quot;&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &lt;div class=&quot;overdiv&quot; style=&quot;position: absolute;&quot;&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&lt;h2&gt;Get a &lt;span style=&quot;color:#E92803;-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;-webkit-text-stroke-color: black&quot;&gt;FREE&lt;/span&gt; Gorgeous Shop in Minutes and Sell Anywhere.&lt;/h2&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&lt;form method=&quot;post&quot; action=&quot;https://www.marclick.com/customer/account/create/&quot;&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &lt;div&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&lt;input required type=&quot;email&quot; name=&quot;email&quot; value=&quot;&quot; style=&quot;border-radius:10px;&quot; class=&quot;form-control&quot; placeholder=&quot;Your Email&quot;&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&lt;div class=&quot;text-left&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&lt;input type=&quot;submit&quot; value=&quot;Get Your Online Shop Now!&quot; class=&quot;btn btn-warning btn--decorated&quot;&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &lt;/div&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&lt;/form&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&lt;p class=&quot;text-left&quot;&gt;No Credit Card Required&lt;/p&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &lt;img src=&quot;img/home_slider/1.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &lt;/li&gt;</p>
```

what should I do to save the html as it is and echo it any time it is needed as a html code

here is my PHP code

```
    $content=$_POST['editor1']; //html
    $seo=addslashes($_POST['keywords']);
    $category=addslashes($_POST['category']);
    $query="INSERT INTO `pages`(`name`,`link`,`seo`,`content`, `category`)
     VALUES 
     ('$title','$permalink','$seo','$content','$category')";
    $result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: Please add your PHP code too, where you're inserting it to the DB.

Comment: I just edited the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use **htmlspecialchars** and **htmlspecialchars_decode** combined with **htmlEntities** ,**html_entity_decode**

**htmlspecialchars — Convert special characters to HTML entities**

See documentation here http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

**htmlspecialchars_decode — Convert special HTML entities back to characters** 
See documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

```
$htmlcode = htmlentities(htmlspecialchars(thehmldata));
echo $htmlcode;

echo html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($htmlcode));
```

Comment: I did that but when I echo the content it show html in browser and it is not rendered as html

Comment: have you look at the console? the html might be wrap with the pre tag

Comment: i updated my answer hope that works on yours because it works here :)

Comment: $content=addslashes($_POST['editor1']); //html
$html=htmlentities(htmlspecialchars($content));
echo html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($html));

Comment: could you try to remove addslashes? and try again?because its really working in here

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes **htmlspecialchars()** or **htmlentities()** gives error while save html markup in database so instead of that use **base64_encode()** or to decode  **base64_decode()**. see attached link for the same

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916834/12489279

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$content=htmlentities($_POST['editor1']);
```

before insert.
And on page direct print it using "echo".