# how to save ckeditor content in mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor to create a blog site. I want to use a combination of PHP and MySQL to save the entire article in a database. If I submit the form holding the ckeditor I get the editor's content in `$_POST['editor']`. I want to save the article in the MySQL database. The following image contains the entire form data. It consists of:

1. **title inside title element.**
2. **article(text,code-snippet,image) inside "editor1" element.**

***`$_POST['editor']` array looks like:***

[image]

How can I save it to a mysql table? Can I save the entire *editor1* element in a column of type *TEXT*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, You can submit your entire article to the database. But, before you submit it; try to use this function:

```
function dataready($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
```

Example:

```
 dataready($_POST['editor']);
```

So you can use whatever you want PDO or Mysqli.

To avoid echoing the HTML elements when you print the article, use this function:

```
  html_entity_decode($article_text);
```

Hope this works for you.

PS. using column type TEXT for your database is fine. You can also use LONGTEXT if you want to add more text to that column.

Comment: thanks for the precise answer.I have one question for you,that is if i use html_entity_decode function an iframe can pop up when i print the post array ?can that impose a security threat?

Comment: You are welcomed. I didn't try that before, but I think if you included the popup code in your article, then it will not work. Regarding the security, no this will not impose security. However, website security is a big issue, you need to read more about it. Stackoverflow has some interesting answers about that, and also you can find good articles about that issue on the internet, just google it.

Comment: OMG i luv this answer and got rid of headache that i had for a month . thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store the Source Code in your database, that's how Wordpress works.

But remember to escape the strings before sending them to database, using:

```
mysqli_escape_string();
```

When you get the post data afterwards, the PHP will just print the HTML on the screen.

Comment: contents are mixed with string ,codesnippet and images. how can i use this function to  escape only the string .Should i pass the whole "editor1" element inside that function? i intend to use PDO over mysqli.What could be the equivalent of that function in PDO?

Comment: And about the last line, are you talking about retrieving data from database?

Answer (score 2):

Simple and easy use base64_encode()

```
$content = base64_encode($editor_content);
```

and when you fetch data use base64_decode()

```
$content = base64_decode($editor_content);
```

Comment: So simple but worked perfectly, Just for those who have old content that is not base64 you will need to add a base64 detecting function for retrieving old content that isn't base64

Comment: How does this work with the possible styling of text. Does this get saved as well and retrieved from DB in a good way?